# lynx program failing with 'Can't access startfile'?

Tags: linux, lynx

lynx program says 'Can't Access `file://localhost/usr/share/doc/HTML/index.html'
    Alert!: Unable to access document.'

Where is the startup config file?
Can someone please provide a solution?

```
# lynx

Can't Access `file://localhost/usr/share/doc/HTML/index.html'
Alert!: Unable to access document.

lynx: Can't access startfile
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default Lynx homepage is set in `/etc/lynx.cfg` by the `STARTFILE` statement. You can set `$LYNX_CFG` to your own config file, or set `$WWW_HOME` to your preferred homepage.

```
export WWW_HOME="http://www.google.com/"
```

Or you could just give an address on the command line:

```
lynx www.google.com
```

---

Aside: You could also try `elinks` or `w3m` browsers.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I ran into this message, and didn't quite understand this responses above. Here's what I learned: The `lynx` STARTFILE is the 'home page' that you see if you don't specify a URL on the command line.

Older versions of `lynx` point to http://lynx.isc.org/ in the config file. Newer versions of `lynx` point to https://lynx.invisible-island.net/ (See the two config's below.)

To stop this message, update to a recent version of `lynx` or update the STARTFILE in the config file. I used `brew update lynx` on my Mac to get the newer version.

**Older version of lynx**

```
### Lynx 2.8.8rel.2, at Thu Jan  2 10:34:54 2020
STARTFILE:http://lynx.isc.org/
HELPFILE:http://lynx.isc.org/release/breakout/lynx_help/lynx_help_main.html
...
```

**Newer version of lynx**

```
### Lynx 2.8.9rel.1, at Thu Jan  2 10:43:33 2020
STARTFILE:https://lynx.invisible-island.net/
HELPFILE:https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/lynx_help_main.html
...
```